# How Should I install Django on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: django, ubuntu-20.04

I am trying to install Djnago on **ubuntu 20.04 LTS**.
**First of all, I used the following command to install Python:**

```
sudo apt-get install python3
```

Python version is **3.8.2**.

Then I used these commands to install Django,
**1st step:** `sudo apt update`
**2nd step:** `sudo apt install python3-pip`

Error is showed in 2nd step and that is,

```
Media change: please insert the disc labeled
 'Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS _Focal Fossa_ - Release amd64 (20200731)'
in the drive '/cdrom/' and press [Enter]
```

When I press **Enter**. It continuously showed but it doesn't solve the problem

*Now, what should I do? Please, help me solving this problem.*

Comment: Please follow this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/64148852/8826621

Comment: Did you put the right disk into the reader?  You seem to be trying to install from multi-disk installation media.  Perhaps you could explain more clearly what this media looks like, how you are installing, etc.  The problem doesn't appear to be django specific ... and frankly, it doesn't appear to be a *programming* question.

Answer (score 3):

Since Python is already installed on Ubuntu 20.04, you should try:

```
pip install Django==3.1.1
```

Here is the documentation about how to install Django on different OS. [Django Documentation](https://www.djangoproject.com/download/)

Comment: Thanks for answer but This command dosen't work. It show an error, and that is "Command 'pip' not found, but there are 18 similar ones.
"

Comment: It seams that you have a problem with your disk. I found  information about your problem here [apt - 'media change'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/386265/media-change-please-insert-the-disc-labeled-when-trying-to-install-ruby-on-ra)

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get update
python -m pip install Django
```

- This will download the latest version of Django for you.
- By using the version name you can get specific version.
- But by doing this you will get the latest stable version

Comment: I used two command and 1st command successfully run but after run 2nd command I showed an error and that is, "Command 'python' not found, did you mean:

  command 'python3' from deb python3
  command 'python' from deb python-is-python3
"  Then I again run to reedit this command as "python3 -m pip install Django
" . But it also showed error,"/usr/bin/python3: No module named pip"

Comment: Please help me, to setup pip in Ubuntu 20.04 version.

Comment: run `which python` or `which python3` and see if you get any file path as output. If you do not get that means your distribution do not have python installed. To install python for debian based distribution run `sudo apt-get install python` and for python3 run `sudo apt-get install python3`